# Is this equivalent to $\omega$-consistency?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Is the following condition equivalent to a first order theory $T$ being $\omega$-consistent?

$\forall y:   \big{(}  \exists x \, [\operatorname {Proof}_T (x,y)] \uparrow \exists  z \, [ \operatorname {Proof}_T(z,\operatorname {neg}(y))]\big{)}$

Where  $\uparrow; \operatorname {Proof}_T(x,y);\operatorname {Proof}_T(x,\operatorname {neg}(y))$ are defined as usual (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick#Background), and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke)).

Why I'm asking this question, is actually because I had the impression before that the above is actually the definition of ordinary consistency. But from the following Wikipedia page on [$\omega$-consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory#Definition), it mentions:

> A theory $T$ that interprets arithmetic is $\omega$-inconsistent if, for some property $P$ of natural numbers (defined by a formula in the language of $T$), $T$ proves $P(0), P(1), P(2)$, and so on (that is, for every standard natural number $n$, $T$ proves that $P(n) $holds), but $T$ also proves that there is some natural number $n$ such that $P(n)$ fails.

Also in the wikipedia article on the proof sketch of the first incompleteness theorem, the [diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Diagonalization), the paragraph discussing the provability of negation of $p$ (where $p$ is the Gödel sentence), it also mentions the role of the assumption of $\omega$-consistency in establishing non-provability of $\neg p$, and so in an ordinary consistent theory (that may not be $\omega$-consistent) I get it that we can have $\exists x \, [\operatorname {Proof}_T(x, \ulcorner \neg p \urcorner)] \land \exists z \, [\operatorname {Proof}_T(z, \ulcorner p \urcorner)]$, the latter being proved at some non-standard $y$.

Now, the above-mentioned consistency statement seems to prove $\omega$-consistency, since it would prevent existence of any proofs of contradicting statements coded by any naturals whether standard or not.

From all of this I also get the impression that the above statement if the naturals coding the proofs are taken to be standard, then it would be equivalent to the ordinary consistency statement.

However, I'm not sure of these, also I'm not sure if this statement is equivalent, weaker, or even stronger than $\omega$-consistency. Hence the question.

Comment: What is the up arrow? exclusive or?

Comment: The Sheffer stroke.

Comment: Am I missing something? Why is it not literally the statement of (ordinary) consistency.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, the ordinary consistency allows failures of the above statement, you can have a theory proving $\neg p$ and at the same time utters the false statement that there exists a natural (non-standard) that codes a proof of $p$. But, here you cannot have that.

Comment: You need a second "Proof()" clause to get what you want: "NAND(prove(A is provable), prove($\neg$A is provable))" roughly. What you've written is just ordinary consistency as @spaceisdarkgreen says.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I don't understand? I've written exactly what you said.

Comment: No, you haven't. Note that my comment has two "proves inside a proves," for a total of **four** instances of the provability predicate - your post has no nested provability, and only **two** instances of the provability predicate. You may have intended additional provability instances, but they're not actually written.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, OK, I'll try squeeze my mind and try fathom what you are saying, I'll make the correction. Thanks!

Comment: @NoahSchweber, What you said works here, simply let $y$ be the statement of $\exists k \, [\operatorname {Proof}_T (k, A)]$ which captures (A is provable),  and its negation captures $\neg$(A is provable). If T is complete I think $\neg$(A is provable) would capture (($\neg$A) is provable). But, anyhow, see my reply to spaceisdarkgreen, there is a difference here that I've mentioned about proofs coded by non-standard naturals which can violate ordinary consistency but not this one.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, I'm under the impression (which might be wrong) that ordinary consistency is the same statement but when we limit it to standard naturals, i.e. $x$ and $z$ above are concrete natural numbers.